# OpenGL - Display array of points

Tags: opengl

I have a 512x512 window, and am generating 262144(ie, 512*512) 2D points and displaying them using glVertex2f. The points are evenly spaced within a range like (-2,-2) to (2,2). After some time, I am generating a different set of 262144 points with a different range like (-1,-1) to (1,1). I define glOrtho as (0, 512, 0, 512, 0, 512). The second matrix of points occupies half the window while the first occupies the whole window. How do I make the second matrix of points also occupy the whole window without changing gluLookAt or specifying different rotation, translation or glOrtho? (it's essentially like a zoom, but replotting different values, and I need the new values to fit the whole window)

Comment: By providing coordinates in your desired range? I'm not sure what kind of magic you expect.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I make the second matrix of points also occupy the whole window without changing gluLookAt or specifying different rotation, translation or glOrtho?

You do it exactly like that. You're not expected to set the projection or modelview matrix "just once". You're supposed to change these matrices as often as required.

OpenGL is a *drawing* API. Don't treat OpenGL as something it is not (scene graph, 3D model displayer, etc.). At the end of the day OpenGL just draws points, lines or triangles, applying some transformations. And changing the transformations on demand and selectively for certain drawing steps is not just acceptable, it's the way of doing things.